# Visual Studio tasklist

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#, tasklist

Ok to the "Task List" in VS sounds pretty great.
But I can't make it work. (I'm using VS2010 shell, and also VS2010 proper and can't make it work in either. Language is F# if that matters)

I have thing like this in my code:

```
let expStatus = ref AwaitingResult 

member takecontrol () =     
             assert (!expStatus<>NoneSubmitted); //UNDONE: This might be possible, and indeed legal, if it happens should wait for cancelation to happen then to hand over
             assert (!expStatus<>BeingWorkedOn); //UNDONE: This might be possible, and indeed legal, if it happens should wait for cancelation to happen then to hand over
             //startThread "run" <| 
             this.RunExp () //Get to work
```

UNDONE is a flag in my settings.
TODO doesn't work either

Any ideas?

Comment: It's 2022 and it's still not working with F# files...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that for me in VS2010 and a fs file in an fs project, it doesn't work.

[Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19299/brian) or [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek) will be able to give a definitive answer, but I suspect that this is one of the things that they haven't got round to coding in the F#/VS tool set.

Comment: By the way, be wary of using the task list for User tasks, because they are *exactly that* - they get stored in the solution *user* file (`suo`), which is generally ignored by source control.

Comment: Yeah I see a bug in our database about TODO/tasklist.  Note also that the F# project system doesn't yet write user-specific stuff to the .suo, more of our feature debt.