# Looking for up-to-date F# PowerPack

Tags: f#, powerpack

Is there someone who working on F# Power Pack ?

Seriously - last update is Dec10 for old F# Core.

So I've got own rebuild for some parts (Linq2sql) for .net4 and new core and I think there is someone else who got the same and someone who is working on it - where can I find it ? Or F# PP is dead ?

Also I can see only lesser compiler fixes. I like [this work](http://tomasp.net/academic/joinads/joinads.pdf) but it's not official tree. OK, just kidding, the question is still being about F# Power Pack.

Comment: How about to make an unofficial fork somewhere. I have a lot of code I could share.

Comment: @Oldrich Svec - I was thinking about it. I wanted to try making own set of up-to-day working parts of it here : https://github.com/nCdy/FS-Damnation (it's really nothing yet) If you got everything to share - share it )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a comment in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/04/22/update-to-the-f-2-0-free-tools-release-corresponding-to-visual-studio-2010-sp1-april-2011-ctp.aspx), updating the F# PowerPack isn't a high priority just yet.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the reason there - what is their current task ?

Comment: @nCdy : I presume they're not allowed to say, or they would have said. But I can only interpret `we have a Visual Studio development deadline` to mean that they have paid/scheduled/budgeted work to finish before spending time on updating an unpaid, mostly-working open-source project.

Comment: the Visual Studio part sounds promising, especially if they are working on F# integration :)

Comment: @nCdy, if you trawl the F# questions here a bit, you'll catch quite a few comments from Brian talking about a big backlog of VS integration work. ([Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119265/visual-studio-tasklist/6120128#6120128) an example from yesterday).